# How to join Date and String-Type in Excel Formulas?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I want a cell to display the current date and some string in addition to it. All formatted as a string e.g. `12.02.2020 My, Name _______` I tried to use `TEXT()` but the formula `=TEXT(TODAY();"dd/mm/yyyy")& "; My, Name _______"` does yield a `VALUE!`-Errormessage. I think it is because my excel isn't interpreting my formatting in this case `"dd/mm/yyyy"` the right way.

I use Office 2016.

The solution was as suspected in my local settings. My excel is set on english but the local settings are set to german. So the right formatting was `tt/MM/JJJJ`.

Comment: You need to be looking at the `concatenate` function.

Comment: Does your local setting use `;` or `,` as the delimiter?

Comment: what happens when you replace `"dd/mm/yyyy"` with other setting options? What can you make work?

Comment: You may have tokens other than `m`,`d`,`y` for month, day , year.  Check your numberformat options and also your Windows Regional Settings.

Comment: no need to edit your question to include the answer. the answer is in the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your locale setting,...

**Example:**
English locale `=Text(Today();"dd/mm/yyyy")`
must be written `=Text(Today();"dd/mm/åååå")` for a Swedish locale  (Year = År)

... or even worse; with an Excel having Swedish text in the menus: function names may have been translated; `today()` could be `idag()`

*I Avoid this as the Plague by only ever installing the ENGLISH version of Office*

Comment: That was super weird. I have german locale settings so `tt/MM/JJJJ` works but my excel is completely in english, so I never thought of that!

Answer (score 3):

You are pretty much there.

Try:

```
=TEXT(TODAY();"dd/mm/yyyy")&" Some rrnadom text here"
```

You could also use CONCATENATE as suggested by Spikey:

```
=CONCATENATE(TEXT(TODAY();"dd/mm/yyyy");" Random Text";" More Randoms")
```

You may need to swap `;` for `,` depending on your locale.

Comment: I am sure this is how it is supposed to work. But I still get an `Value!`-Error, I think it is because of the date-format specifier `dd/mm/yyy`. I tried only `=Text(Today();"dd/mm/yyyy")`and it yields the error.

Answer (score 2):

CONCATENATE will solve issue
=CONCATENATE(TEXT(TODAY(),"dd/mm/yyyy")," ", "yourtext)

Comment: I am sure this is how it is supposed to work, but I still get the `Value!`-Error. I think `"dd/mm/yyyy"` is the issue.

Comment: Dear i checked formula in excel . Could you please send exact formula did you try

Comment: `=CONCATENATE(TEXT(TODAY();"DD/MM/YYYY");" "; "yourtext")` as I have a local delimiter `;` instead of `,`

Comment: Dear , works for clear parameterand ; its not working at them . If you have ; in text or data is better have seprate column for data and your text and concat them with formula as below =CONCATENATE(TEXT(A2, "yyyy-mm-dd")," ", B2)